# Web Form based login in Java

Tags: java, authentication, web.xml, servlet-filters

How can I block access to the site if a user is not logged in?

Under web.xml > Security I checked Form authentication then I selected Login and Error page, but I don't know how to block the access and redirect the user to the login page.

Do I need a filter? If so, how can I get the login url I specified?

And how should I call the validation method? I saw in some examples this code

```
    <form method=post action="j_security_check">
     <input type="text" name="j_username" />
     <input type="password" name="j_password" />
    </form>
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent people who aren't logged in from viewing resources, you use security constraints.  Something like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>all-resources</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: It's working, thanks! If you know can you edit the answer and give me an example on how should I call my user validation method, redirect and stuff...?

Comment: What j_security_check actually does depends on what app server you're using.  If you want to make your own, you'll want to read up on JAAS:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JAASRealm

Note there are lots of web frameworks that have all of that ready to go for you, not a whole lot of non-academic reason to reimplment JAAS yourself.